# Remove trailing question mark with form method=get

Tags: html, forms, button

I'm using a form button to send me to a page when I click it http://example.com/folder/upload/ but for some reason when I click the button it adds a trailing question mark at the end like this: http://example.com/folder/upload/?

My current code looks like this:

```
<form method="get" action="http://example.com/folder/upload/"><button type="submit" class="green button"><i  class="photo" ></i></button></form>
```

How can I get rid of the question mark without using method="post" because I want users to be able to refresh the page without having the Confirm Form Re-submission dialog popping up.

Is there another way of fixing this without using method="post"?

I'd prefer a solution without using onclick or any javascript if possible.

Comment: Use a link (`<a href>`) and style it like a button

Answer (score 6):

The question mark is part of the [definition of form submission with the GET method](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.1), so no.

You can get rid of the question mark by using a link instead of artificial form submission that does not really submit anything. [Links want to be links](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/links.html).

Comment: I see, so I would have to turn that button into an image link. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this on the server side, using a redirect, if you have control of the server.

Example for the php language:

Add this

```
 if (isset($_GET['keywords']) && !empty($_GET['keywords'])) { 
    $key=$_GET['keywords'];
    header("Location:http://website.com/search/$key"); }
```

**Add For this form**

```
<form  method="get">
    <input type="text"  name="keywords">
</form>
```

Comment: use $key = trim($key);